# Do I need to use the article "the" with the word "data" in the following sentence?

Tags: articles

*To discover the real statistics behind missing children, I turned to the following organizations for **the** data.*

Or should it be as follows:

*To discover the real statistics behind missing children, I turned to the following organizations for data.*

Comment: I think either works

Comment: By adding the article "the" you're implying that you're asking them specifically for "the real statistics behind missing children". By omitting "the" then the data you're asking for could be more general. However, it doesn't change the meaning in any obvious way, and I think both are grammatical.

Comment: Is there specific data that you know of (*the*), or are you looking for any data at all?

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I can see I need to use the article.